# Outstanding password keeper w/ password generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

After almost completely redoing the [first version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/108434/78136) I think I finally have it. I still have a few things to add/change, but I think it's pretty good and safe. I've improved security features as well as overall functionality.

I haven't run this program through pycharm yet, so there might be a few `PEP 8` errors. It took me a few weeks just trying to learn about cryptography (not an easy subject). For @GarethRees [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108436?noredirect=1), I really didn't even start on version 2 until I implemented some sort of encryption that worked perfectly on Version 1. I tried using `gpg` as he recommended, but could never figure it out. I even tried it again after figuring out how to use `pycrypto`.

If there are any bugs just point them out you don't have to write a full review just whatever you think should be changed or added post it. I really appreciate feedback and will upvote all. If you want a `.exe` version just ask and I'll post a link. Hope everyone likes it.

```
#Programmer: DeliriousSyntax
#Date: 12-9-15
#File: AccountKeeperV2.py

#This program lets you store and create passwords

import CustomFunctions as CF
import pyperclip
import random
import shelve
import EcstaticCryption
import string

#Encrypting and Decrypting is done with pycrypto

"""
Task List:
Hide key after hitting enter
Create a settings GUI
Let user continuously generate a password untill satisfied
When changing password let user pick a new random password
Use string.punctuation in character list without messing up printing
Add Exclude similar characters option
Let user save settings without opening script
"""


class main:
    LOWER = True
    UPPER = True
    NUMBERS = True
    SYMBOLS = True
    COPY = True

    File = "Keeper.dat"

    template = ('\n-  Account:  {}  '
                '- Username:  {}  '
                '-  Password:  {} '
                ' -')

    key = input('Key: ')
    EC = EcstaticCryption.AESCipher(key)

    @property
    def CHARACTERS(self):
        CHAR = []
        if self.LOWER:CHAR.append(string.ascii_lowercase)
        if self.UPPER:CHAR.append(string.ascii_uppercase)
        if self.SYMBOLS:CHAR.append('!#$%&()*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~')
        if self.NUMBERS:CHAR.append(string.digits)
        return CHAR

    def all_accounts(self):
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            print('\n')
            for account in f:
                print(account, end='  ')
            print('\n')

    def all_users(self, account):
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            print('\n')
            for user in f[account]:
                print(user, end='  ')
            print('\n')

    def check_account(self, account):
        list_of_accounts = []
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            if account in f:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def check_username(self, account, username):
        list_of_users = []
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            try:
                if username in f[account]:
                    return True
                else:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                pass
            return False

    def generate_password(self, digits_in_pass):
        holder = []
        for _ in range(digits_in_pass):
            temp = random.SystemRandom().choice(self.CHARACTERS)
            holder.append(random.SystemRandom().choice(temp))
        return ''.join(holder)

    def save_account(self, entry):
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            try:
                holder_account = f[entry[0]]
            except KeyError:
                holder_account = {}
            holder_account[entry[1]] = entry
            f[entry[0]] = holder_account

    def new_account(self, log=True):
        """Creates a new random password"""
        print('\n')
        account = input("Account: ")
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            while True:
                username = input("Username: ")
                existing_username = self.check_username(account, username)
                if not existing_username:
                    break
                print("This account already exists!")
        password = input("Password (Type \"random\" for random password): ")
        if password.lower() == 'random':
            digits_in_pass = CF.valid_int("Length of password: ")
            password = self.generate_password(digits_in_pass)
        encrypted_password = self.EC.encrypt(password)
        entry = [account, username, encrypted_password]
        self.save_account(entry)
        if self.COPY:
            pyperclip.copy(password)
        if log:
            print(self.template.format(entry[0], entry[1], password))

    def print_account(self, account, username):
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            entry = f[account][username]
            password = self.EC.decrypt(entry[2])
            print(self.template.format(entry[0], entry[1], password))
            if self.COPY:
                pyperclip.copy(password)

    def change_username(self, account, username, log=True):
        new_username = input('\nEnter new username: \n   ->')
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            account_holder = f[account]
            account_holder[new_username] = account_holder.pop(username)
            account_holder[new_username][1] = new_username
            f[account] = account_holder
            if log:
                entry = f[account][new_username]
                password = self.EC.decrypt(entry[2])
                print(self.template.format(entry[0], entry[1], password))

    def change_password(self, account, username, log=True):
        new_password = input('Enter new password: \n   ->')
        with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
            f[account][username][2] = self.EC.encrypt(new_password)
            if log:
                entry = f[account][username]
                print(self.template.format(entry[0], entry[1], new_password))

    def delete_account(self, account, username):
        confirmation = input("\nType 'DELETE' to confirm deletion of this account...\n   ->")
        if confirmation.lower() == 'delete':
            with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
                account_holder = f[account]
                try:
                    del account_holder[username]
                    f[account] = account_holder
                    print('\nAccount deleted...')
                except KeyError:
                    print('Error deleting account!')

    def account_menu(self, account, username):
        print("\nAccount Found! What's next?\n"
        " 1) Print account\n"
        " 2) Change username\n"
        " 3) Change password\n"
        " 4) Delete account\n"
        " 5) Cancel")
        account_choice = input("   ->")
        if account_choice == '1':
            self.print_account(account, username)
        elif account_choice == '2':
            self.change_username(account, username)
        elif account_choice == '3':
            self.change_password(account, username)
        elif account_choice == '4':
            self.delete_account(account, username)
        else:
            pass

    def find_account(self):
        account = input('\n\nAccount: ')
        while account == 'all accounts':
            self.all_accounts()
            account = input('Account: ')
        existing_account = self.check_account(account)
        if existing_account:
            username = input('Username: ')
            while username == 'all users':
                self.all_users(account)
                username = input('Username: ')
            existing_user = self.check_username(account, username)
            if existing_user:
                self.account_menu(account, username)
            else:
                print('\nWe could not find your account.')
        else:
            print('\nCould not find any {} accounts.'.format(account))

    def program_start(self):
        """MAIN"""
        choice = None
        while True:
            print("\n\n\nMenu:\n"
                  " 1) Add an account\n"
                  " 2) Search for an existing account\n"
                  " 3) Exit")
            choice = input("   ->")
            if choice == "1":
                self.new_account()
            elif choice == "2":
                self.find_account()
            else:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Welcome to Account Keeper V2")
    m = main()
    m.program_start()
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers, or comment on why you don't find any of the current answers good enough for acception.

Comment: @holroy Oh yeah thanks, just been busy and haven't check in on code review in a while. Between school, work, gym, and trying to create a big project to get noticed by employers it's hard to find time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen your question and would like to give you a full review, but haven't had the time yet. So now I decided to give you some of the recommendations, and then we'll see if I get the time to complete it or add to it later on.

- *Move shelve handling to class level* – Instead of opening/closing the shelve all the time, I would suggest to let it follow the lifetime of the class, and add a `sync` method to the class. This would reduce the file operations, and you can keep the shelve open within the class.

  This would allow for all of the read access to be almost instant as the file is already read into memory (and the encrypted password should *still* be encrypted). And when doing changing password methods, you could trigger a sync, writing the shelve back to the file.

  Two links which might be helpful in doing this:

  - [Persistent dict with multiple standard file formats (Python recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/) – Which provides some structural stuff related to you use of shelve
  - [Safely using destructors in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python) – Related to handling lifetime opening and closing of the shelve (in a slightly different context)
- *A better class name* – `main` is a terrible name, you should choose a better name like `PasswordHandler` or `AccountHandler`. As already suggested I would move the shelve handling to the outer level, and possibly add a few class methods. I.e. a static class method to verify if a user has entered the correct password would be nice to have.
- *Allow methods **not** to use input* – To improve the interface, I would change the methods allowing input to accept that input to be predefined as a parameter. I'll show some code for one of the functions which could accomplish this:

  ```
  def change_password(self, account, username, new_password=None, log=True):
          if not new_password:
              new_password = input('Enter new password: \n   ->')

          with shelve.open(self.File) as f:
              f[account][username][2] = self.EC.encrypt(new_password)
              if log:
                  entry = f[account][username]
                  print(self.template.format(entry[0], entry[1], new_password))
  ```

  This still uses the old code for the shelve handling, but you'll get the gist of the idea.
- *Let methods return list, not do the actual output* – Instead of letting your methods, like `all_users`, do the print, in general it's better to let the method returning the list of users for extra handling, i.e. printing or sorting before printing or whatever...
- *Move class level code into `__init__`* – Doing stuff like `key = input(...)` is very strange, and should be moved into a method of it's own, namely the `__init__`, which is automatically called whenever you create an instance of your class.

There are some other minor aspects still not covered (neither in mine, nor the other answer which just came in), but these matters are some of the main issues I see in your code.

Comment: I thought `__init__` was for items that would change and not constants.?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax, `__init__` is for class instanstation cases, yes. Having rogue code executed at import time is not good coding strategy. If you want them as class constants, then you should consider using static methods or similar. But having a `input()` at class level, which could be triggered wherevere, is a real code smell

Answer (score 2):

This looks pretty good - I'd say the biggest opportunities for improvement are in style, ease of i18n, and documentation (I have no idea if any of these have been mentioned in a previous post, as I haven't read it).

I'm going to start with documentation - generally, **most** of your methods and parameter names are fairly straightforward, however if you write useful docstrings (I appreciate the [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) standard) you can use a tool like [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) to create documentation (if you think anyone else might ever want to use your tool as a developer).  Even if you don't think anyone else will ever program with this, writing documentation will help you understand it later.

On that note, your module as a whole should probably have a brief docstring describing its overall purpose.

I don't know that I like how hardcoded some things are (for example `LOWER`, `UPPER`, `File`, etc).  It would be nice if these could be set somewhere, or passed as CLA, or in a config file, etc.

In `check_account` you don't ever use `list_of_accounts`, and you could just `return account in f` instead of having the if statements.  Likewise, in `check_username` you don't use `list_of_users`, and you could probably simplify the conditions.  I'm not familiar with `shelve`, but assuming it quacks like a `dict` you could just do `return username in f.get(account, {})` and then avoid the try-except, the if-else, etc.  If you don't want to do that, you don't need the `else:pass` at all.

You could probably turn `generate_password` into a list comprehension.

```
def generate_password(self, digits_in_pass):
    func = random.SystemRandom().choice
    return ''.join(func(func(self.CHARACTERS)) for _ in digits_in_pass)
```

This should be equivalent.

In `save_account` you could (presumably) use `f.get()` instead of the try-except.

In all of the places you use `input` I'd rather see you take that input as a parameter - this separates concerns in case you want to stop asking on the command line, and lets you build out whatever front-end you want.

In `new_account` you can use single quotes instead of escaping the double quotes, which is cleaner IMHO.  I'd also strip the string in case they have whitespace on the ends, and if they have something close to `random` (use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)) maybe emit a warning in case they misspelled it.

You have lots of magic numbers - maybe instead of indexing at 0, 1, and 2, use `ACCOUNT_INDEX = 0` (or something).  Then if you change the order, or use a new scheme, its easier to change it.

`program_start` shouldn't be a part of the class - it should be another function that makes use of the class.

Internationalization (i18n) is important - what if someone wanted to use a different language?  I'd say that you should create a class (or something) that has all of the string literals you use as properties, and then returns them based on some locale or language that has been set.  Then you can add translations easily, if you wanted to expand your userbase.

In terms of style - I don't really like the onelineing in `CHARACTERS` - you aren't losing points for adding some newlines, or at least spaces.

Your naming could use a little work - a class named `main` is not even a little bit helpful.  I'd recommend something like `AccountKeeper` or `PasswordManager` or something like that.  `CHARACTERS` is also not as helpful - maybe `VALID_CHARACTERS` would be better?  Also, `File` isn't as helpful - either make it a constant as `FILE` or a variable as `file`.

`all_accounts` implies that you should get a list or something - calling it `display_all_accounts` is more honest - same for `all_users`.

Constants should be named in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`, classes in `PascalCase`, method/function/variable names in `lower_snake_case`.  You can read more about naming and style conventions in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)